# Easy example of commit scheme not binding

Tags: hash, authentication, commitments

I'm told that the following commit scheme:

$(c,k) = Commit(x;r) = (Enc_r(x),(x,r))$

Does not bind which means that the sender could produce $c,k,k'$ such that:

$Open(c,k) \neq Open(c,k')$

I know this is a very basic example but how can I reason about it?

Comment: The attacker can decrypt $c$ using various keys producing various plaintexts.

Comment: @Rodrigo Did you mean a commitment scheme that is not unconditionally binding, but rely on a hard problem for binding property to hold?

Comment: @CodesInChaos that's the answer I wanted maybe you want to elaborate it a bit and put it as answer. If not I'll do it myself. Thanks